# How do I get headless VNC working?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, vnc

I'm using a headless Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.1 LTS. I think it was around the time I installed the .1 update that VNC stopped working. It worked forever before that.

I'm using the built-in gnome-remote-desktop that you activate in the settings. It is set to allow VNC with a password. I used to have a dummy VGA adapter connected but when it stopped working I switched to a dummy HDMI adapter, which didn't help.

The behavior I'm experiencing varies on the platform I'm using. On a Windows desktop with VNCViewer or TightVNC Viewer, when I connect I see my Ubuntu desktop for a fraction of a second and then the error: "Reconnecting to VNC Server...Protocol Error: bad rectangle: 5376x0 at 0,5418 exceeds 1920x1080 at 0,0". If I use the VNCViewer app on iOS, it connects but I just see a mouse arrow on an empty black screen.

I should also be able to use RDP, right? If I try that, I get the error: "An authentication error has occurred. The token supplied to the function is invalid."

Also, it appears that somehow the gnome-remote-desktop process is only listening on TCP6 and I don't know why.

```
david@zoidberg:$ sudo netstat -anp | grep 5900
[sudo] password for david:
tcp6       0      0 :::5900                 :::*                    LISTEN      1473/gnome-remote-d
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I experienced this same issue.  In my case, this issue cleared up when I changed the the display quality to medium on the connection properties -> options screen on the VNC client viewer.

Comment: Ye gods, you’re right! Worked for me too. Thanks!!

Comment: Oh my! Thanks, John! I spent hours trying to figure this out, but it was so simple, and not even anything that is documented. This is a gem!